# Angular function shows updated value first time only

Tags: angular, angular10

### html

```
 <input type="file" [(ngModel)]="profile.myFile1" (change)="handleFileInfo($event.target.files, 'myFile1')">    
 <div *ngIf="filesExists('myFile1')">
      <span>Size: {{getFileSize('myFile1')}}</span>                  
 </div>


 <input type="file" [(ngModel)]="profile.myFile2" (change)="handleFileInfo($event.target.files, 'myFile2')">
 <div *ngIf="filesExists('myFile2')">
      <span class="photo-size">Size: {{getFileSize('myFile2')}}</span>                  
 </div>
```

### ts file code

```
    handleFileInfo(files: FileList, fileTypeName: string) { 
       // Other code ....
      let fileObj: FileObj = { type: fileTypeName, file: files.item(0), fileSizeText: fileSizeText, isValid: validSizeFlag };
      this.commonService.addOrReplaceFiles(this.files, fileObj); //Add or update the object array with the file fileObj
    }

    getFileSize(fileTypeName: string) {
      let fileObj = this.files.find(o => o.type === fileTypeName); //this.files : Object array
      return fileObj.fileSizeText;
    }
```

---

I have multiple file upload fields. If I upload a file it shows the file size.
If I reupload the file again it shows the new file preview. But the getFileSize() function value never gets updated, it shows first uploaded file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getFileSize` only gets called the first time the HTML is rendered. It has no way to know if your `myFile1` has changed. I suggest having a `myFile1Size` variable that gets updated in your TS code whenever you upload a new file to hold the information about the size and bind that into the HTML as `{{myFile1Size}}`.

Comment: Thanks. How could I forgot this one. Created an object array to keep the fileSizeText. Now it's working fine.